# Error setting initial member value of an enum object from local variable

Tags: typescript, enums, initialization

Typescript example in [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20firstValue%3A%20number%20%3D%20100%3B%0D%0Aenum%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Lion%20%3D%20firstValue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Tiger%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Horse%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Fish%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

I am trying to set the initial member value of an enum object, and that initial value comes from a const (numeric).
In this case the all the following values give a TS error: "Enum member must have initializer."

Is this not allowed?
Why are the following members not set to the preceding enum member plus one?

For brevity here's the code, but you can see it in the playground link above:

```
const firstValue: number = 100;
enum Animal {
    Lion = firstValue,
    Tiger,  // gives error
    Horse,  // gives error
    Fish    // gives error
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed not allowed at the moment - when following another enum member with an initializer, an enum member only auto-increments when the computed value is statically known. Right now, that only includes numeric literals and other enum members whose values are statically known, but the analysis doesn't currently include `const` declarations.

You could get around this with

```
enum FirstValue {
    firstValue = 100
}
```

and use `FirstValue.firstValue` instead of `firstValue`.

Comment: Actually I may have found another limitation. I need the enum FirstValue to be in an external file (because it needs to be used from multiple files), and when I export it from that external file, and then I import it in the file where the Animal enum is, then I can't use it anymore, because it gives me this error: `[ts] Type 'FirstValue' is not assignable to type 'Animal' `