# react native : What is the way to create an enum with 3 color types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my example I try add a variable `button_gradient_color` with 3 parameters of color and it shows an error.
The error is:
Enum member must have initializer

What is the way to create an enum with 3 color types ?

```
export enum Colors {
 background_color = '#000060',
 button_gradient_color = '#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a'
};
```

this is the LinearGradient

```
<LinearGradient
            colors={ Colors.button_gradient_color1,Colors.button_gradient_color2,Colors.button_gradient_color3}

 >
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error setting initial member value of an enum object from local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708914/error-setting-initial-member-value-of-an-enum-object-from-local-variable)

Comment: no its not my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently one variable initialized to multiple values is not allowed. You can either separate the color gradients into 3 different variables like below, if that helps you in your situation.

```
export enum Colors {
 background_color = '#000060',
 button_gradient_color1 = '#4c669f', 
 button_gradient_color2 = '#3b5998',
 button_gradient_color3 =  '#192f6a'
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIQDbQM5wDeAsAFBwBGAhgMYDWA5lBMogCYD6NO0cAvHADkAYgAM40QDZRggDRlKyGDAiIOTKmwCWSGFx5QAjPyHCALDUmSAnADM5cBRSUq1G7bv24oAJhMiAZgoAVmtrAA45JxdVdShNHUQ9bm8Ak1NDax9bSSpBMgBfAG4gA)

And you could refer like Colors.button_gradient_color1 perhaps.

While passing it to the LinearGradient component you can do is:

```
<LinearGradient colors={[ Colors.button_gradient_color1, Colors.button_gradient_color2  Colors.button_gradient_color3 ]} >
```

Comment: i didnt knew that multiple values are not allowed.

Comment: @emma, does the above answer suffice?

Comment: so how i put it now in the lineargradient component ?

` <LinearGradient
            colors={{ Colors.button_gradient_color1 = '#4c669f', 
            Colors.button_gradient_color2 = '#3b5998',
            Colors.button_gradient_color3 =  '#192f6a'}}
            
          >
`

Comment: `<LinearGradient colors={{ Colors.button_gradient_color1, Colors.button_gradient_color2  Colors.button_gradient_color3}} >`
If you are trying to pass it to the component then this should suffice. since, the values are already assigned in the enum declaration you don't have to initialize them again while passing.

Comment: so what i should do ?

Comment: @emma, <LinearGradient colors={{ Colors.button_gradient_color1, Colors.button_gradient_color2  Colors.button_gradient_color3}} > as I wrote in my comment above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236830/discussion-between-emma-and-azher-aleem).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this since the enum has already been declared

```
  <LinearGradient
    Colors={[
      Colors.button_gradient_color1, 
      Colors.button_gradient_color2,
      Colors.button_gradient_color3
    ]}
  >
```